# Implement enumerator using turing machine - redundant prints

Tags: math, turing-machines, decidable

In the following algorithm: 
[image: algorithm]

we implement an enumerator using a turing machine and the enumerator is supposed to output the language accepted by the turing machine.  The accepted words from Σ* are printed multiple times (each iteration previously printed words will be printed again).

Why can't we just say - "for each word in Σ* run M on it. If it accepts then print, if rejects then move on to the next word". Then we won't print each word more than once.

Why the unnecessary prints?

The algorithm from the image is:

If a TM `M` recognizes a language `A`, we can construct the following enumerator for `A`. Assume `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, ... is a list of possible strings in `Σ*`.

`E` = “Ignore the input

1) Repeat the following for `i` = 1, 2, 3, ...

2) Run `M` for `i` steps on each input `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, . . . `si`.

3) If any computations accept, print out corresponding `sj`.”

If `M` accepts a particular string, it will appear on the list generated by `E` (in fact infinitely many times)

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't really seem on-topic for Stack Overflow [computerscience.se] is a better fit. In any event -- why call the prints "unnecessary"? The entire point seems to be enumerating the language by outputting the words one after another (as they are discovered). The print *is* the output. You almost seem to be asking "why is this enumerator enumerating the language?"

Comment: No - the enumerator does print but it will print each accepted word more than once, just like it is stated in the photo - " infinitely many times". Why not print each word only once ? why print " infinitely many times" ?

Comment: So that is your question. The algorithm runs M on each of `s1, ..., si` *for `i` steps*. This is a standard trick to get around the the fact that the computation might fail to halt on a word which isn't in the language. With each new `i` you *could* only rerun M on the inputs for which the computations have not yet halted. As a side effect of the author's way, it reruns each accepting computation infinitely many times. It doesn't hurt to print something when it is found. It also doesn't hurt to only print things once. There is no deep reason for the authors phrasing the proof like that.

Comment: To re-word John's answer: For a language to be Turing recognizable its machine `M` is allowed to never halt for some words not in the language. [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is famously undecidable. So you can't just run `M` from `E` on an arbitrary input `si` as you suggest, because it may never halt. It means you need some more clever trick and running `M` for a limited number of steps is such a trick. But yes, you can do even more clever trick to print each word only once.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments: the problem is that some computation might not terminate. So if you do them sequentially, the ones after the first non-terminating computation will never be executed.

The given algorithm uses the standard technique to work around this: [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)).

You can change step 3 to "If any computation accepts after `i` steps, then print" - then there are no unnecessary prints. But then you have to count the steps during each simulation, which means some extra work. The author choses an option that is simple to program, but not very efficient.